# Get a File Descriptor Handle from FileStream

Tags: c#, mono, monomac

I'm using this library https://github.com/ahawker/NLibsndfile for convert audio files with libSndFile from C#, i did this method, for the conversion (coverts wav to aiff):

```
        string sourcePath = "/User/Dev/Desktop/a.wav";
        string targetPath = "/User/Dev/Desktop/b.aiff";

        var file = File.Create(targetPath);
        file.Close();
        file.Dispose();
        IntPtr ptrTargetFile = file.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        LibsndfileInfo wavInfo = new LibsndfileInfo();
        LibsndfileInfo aiffInfo = new LibsndfileInfo();
        LibsndfileApi api = new LibsndfileApi();

        var wavFile = api.Open(sourcePath, LibsndfileMode.Read, ref wavInfo);
        var aiffFile = api.OpenFileDescriptor((int)ptrTargetFile, LibsndfileMode.Rdwr, ref aiffInfo, 0);

        aiffInfo.Channels = wavInfo.Channels;
        aiffInfo.SampleRate = wavInfo.SampleRate;
        aiffInfo.Format = LibsndfileFormat.Aiff;

        short[] buffer = new short[512];

        long countOfItemsWritten = 0;
        long countOfItemsReaded = 0;

        while ((countOfItemsReaded=api.ReadItems(wavFile, buffer, buffer.Length))>0)
            countOfItemsWritten = api.WriteItems(aiffFile, buffer, countOfItemsReaded);

        api.Close(wavFile);
        api.Close(aiffFile);
```

The problem is at time to open the aiff file, the method `api.OpenFileDescriptor` always return an null pointer. The library method is this: `internal static extern IntPtr sf_open_fd(int handle, LibsndfileMode mode, ref LibsndfileInfo info, int closeHandle);`

Any idea why is failing the operation? or how to get the file Descriptor Handler from FileStream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the descriptor like so:

First use [`FileStream.SafeFileHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.filestream.safefilehandle.aspx) and use the value of that to access [`SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousgethandle.aspx)

So: `IntPtr handle = fileStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();`